# Refreshing a page as an option in a javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

The result I want:

Setting a new password. Using modal overlay leanmodal to show result with javascript ajax doing the POST. Before saving the script first checks the new password has not been used the previously ie current pasword, pswdA, pswdB and pswdC. If the pass word matches one of these we want to stop there and return to the last view to enter and repeat password, in my case the same page with the modal overlay refreshed.  The script that follows attempts this but whatever method I use the site navigates to the previous page which contained a solitary old password field, before the new password page where I want the user to be. Here is the script:

```
 // http://www.webstutorial.com/insert-record-into-database-using-ajax-how-to-insert-data-into-database-using-ajax/ajax
function verifyNewPassword()
    {
        var term_newPassword = $('#newPassword').val(); //Storing the value of textbox into a variable
        var term_mainPw = $('#mainPw').val();
        var term_pswdA = $('#pswdA').val();
        var term_pswdB = $('#pswdB').val();
        var term_pswdC = $('#pswdC').val();

        if(term_newPassword === term_mainPw || term_newPassword === term_pswdA || term_newPassword === term_pswdB || term_newPassword === term_pswdC)  //Checking for NULL
            {
                $('#propspectDiv').html('<h3>Password previously used<h3>');   //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
                $('#newPassword').addClass('error'); 
                $('#pswdA').addClass('error'); 
                $('#pswdB').addClass('error');
                $('#pswdC').addClass('error');                     //Adding the error class to the progress DIV
                success : function(data){
                window.setTimeout(function()
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    $(document).attr('location').href='enterNewPassword.php'
                }, 2000);
                }
                return;
            }else{
                $('#newPassword').removeClass('error');
                $('#pswdA').removeClass('error');
                $('#pswdB').removeClass('error');
                $('#pswdC').removeClass('error');
                $('#propspectDiv').removeClass('error'); //Removing the error class from the progress DIV
                $('#propspectDiv').html('Submitting your Request.<div><img src="images/progress.gif" /></div>');//Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : 'saveNewPW.php', //Declaration of file, in which we will send the data
                data:{
                        "newPassword" : term_newPassword, //we are passing these values in URL
                        "mainPw" : term_mainPw,
                        "pswdA" : term_pswdA,
                        "pswdB" : term_pswdB,
                        "pswdC" : term_pswdC,
                    },
                success : function(data){
                window.setTimeout(function()
                {
                    $('#propspectDiv').html(''); //Prints the progress text into our Progress DIV
                    $('#data').css("display","block");  //Changes the style of table from display:none to display:block
                    $('#data').html(data);  //Prints the data into the table
                }, 1000);

                window.setTimeout(function()
                {
                    $(document).attr('location').href='mainMenu.php'
                }, 3000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

If I use the browser controls to reload (with a message about resubmitting the form) the page does refresh correctly to the page I want.

I have tried all other suggestions ie window.option.reload(true) and variants but all with the same result.

Ay suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Well you sure seem to have a huge list of what you need, are we getting paid for this?

Comment: For a page reload try ``localtion.reload(true)``...

Comment: Another reload is simply `window.location.href = window.location.href;`

Comment: No I have tried those and they don't work. From what I read this has something to do with the ajax fully executing but haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: Finally sorted. All suggestions posted here are probably correct. Found issue with logic in the file from which this was being called where conditional statements were falling through to an option to link back to the previous page.